# How Does Vagrant Talk to a Box It Is Provisioning

Tags: ssh, vagrant, provisioning

How does Vagrant talk to a box it is provisioning? Does it use SSH, or WinRM (on Windows), or VBoxManager, or what?

Answer (score 0):

As of Vagrant 1.2.4 (and VirtualBox 4.2.16), if I understand correctly Vagrant [uses SSH for provisioning a box](http://vagrant.1086180.n5.nabble.com/How-Does-Vagrant-Talk-to-Provisioners-ssh-td160.html). As noted in the link, this SSH communication path will eventually become a Vagrant abstraction -- you will just assume that you have a shell that you can automagically control.